How to use `for_each` on a to be created resource in Terraform
I have 3 private and 3 public subnets, and I want to create either 1 or 2 NAT Gateways depending on the environment.
So, for dev and staging there should be 1 NAT Gateway, and for production two.
Since I can't use for_each with subnets as it is one more than I need, I decided to create the Elastic IPs with count.
resource "aws_eip" "elastic_ip" {
  count = var.environment == "prod" ? 2 : 1
  vpc = true
    
  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "eip-${var.name_suffix}-${count.index}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed Elastic IP"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
  })
}

Now I want to create the NAT Gateways depending on the number of Elastic IPs created, like this:
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw" {
  for_each      = aws_eip.elastic_ip
  allocation_id = each.value.id
  subnet_id     = CHALLENGE 2
    
  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "nat-gw-${var.name_suffix}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed NAT Gateway"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
  })
}

but here I have two challenges.

it complaints about aws_eip.elastic_ip being a tuple. I have tried using toset(), but it didn't work
I need to dynamically pull the IDs of two out of three subnets.

Is this actually possible without extra locals or variables?
UPDATE
Here the code for subnets. I have two of this; one for private subnets and this one for public.
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {
  for_each = var.public_subnet
     
  availability_zone = each.value["az"]
  cidr_block        = each.value["cidr"]
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
    
  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "public-subnet-${var.name_suffix}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed Subnet"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
    AZ          = each.value["az"]
  })
}

And I'm passing a variable with the az and cidr blocks:
public_subnet = {
  subnet_a = {
    az = "eu-west-1a"
    cidr = "10.10.0.0/24"
  }
  subnet_b = {
    az = "eu-west-1b"
    cidr = "10.10.1.0/24"
  }
  subnet_c = {
    az = "eu-west-1c"
    cidr = "10.10.2.0/24"
  }
}


Can you add the code for subnets as well?

@MarkoE added the code for subnets.

You can use count in aws_nat_gateway.nat_gw too and access the aws_eip.elastic_ip resource with an index like this: aws_eip.elastic_ip[count.index].
This would look something like this:
resource "aws_eip" "elastic_ip" {
  count = var.environment == "stg" ? 1 : 2
  vpc = true

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "eip-${var.name_suffix}-${count.index}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed Elastic IP"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
  })
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw" {
  count = var.environment == "stg" ? 1 : 2
  allocation_id = aws_eip.elastic_ip[count.index].id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public_subnet[count.index].id

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "nat-gw-${var.name_suffix}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed NAT Gateway"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
  })
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {
  for_each= var.public_subnet
     
  availability_zone = each.value["az"]
  cidr_block        = each.value["cidr"]
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
    
  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "public-subnet-${var.name_suffix}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed Subnet"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
    AZ          = each.value["az"]
  })
}


Another option might be to use the splat expression combined with toset. But I think terraform will complain because it cannot determine the values of aws_eip.elastic_ip until after the apply.
But I still wanted to mention it and it would look like this:
resource "aws_eip" "elastic_ip" {
  count = var.environment == "stg" ? 1 : 2
  vpc = true

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "eip-${var.name_suffix}-${count.index}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed Elastic IP"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
  })
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw" {
  for_each = toset(aws_eip.elastic_ip[*].id)

  allocation_id = each.value
  subnet_id     = CHALLENGE 2

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "nat-gw-${var.name_suffix}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed NAT Gateway"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
  })
}


Still wouldn't work because the subnet IDs have different keys.

so both options work, but as @Marko E is saying the subnet_ids is still not possible to get.

Can't you do the same for the subnets? Use count and access your local variable with an index

I've edited my answer accordingly

no, because subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_subnet[count.index].id does not have aws_subnet.public_subnet[INT]. It has aws_subnet.public_subnet["subnet_{a,b,c}"].

You could use count for this too... But thats getting kinda ugly ig :/

After making some changes and playing around with the code, this example should work:
locals {
  non_prod_nat_gateway  = { for k, v in aws_subnet.public_subnet : k => v.availability_zone if k != "subnet_a" && k != "subnet_b" }
  prod_nat_gateways = { for k, v in aws_subnet.public_subnet : k => v.availability_zone if k != "subnet_c" }
}

resource "aws_eip" "elastic_ip" {
  for_each = var.environment != "prod" ? local.non_prod_nat_gateway : local.prod_nat_gateways

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "eip-${var.name_suffix}-${each.key}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed Elastic IP"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
  })
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw" {
  for_each      = aws_eip.elastic_ip
  allocation_id = each.value.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.private_subnet[each.key].id

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "nat-gw-${var.name_suffix}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed NAT Gateway"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
  })
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {
  for_each = var.public_subnet

  availability_zone = each.value["az"]
  cidr_block        = each.value["cidr"]
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "public-subnet-${var.name_suffix}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed Subnet"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
    AZ          = each.value["az"]
  })
}

It does not provide much of the dynamic functionality you are probably aiming for, but the rest should work.
A bit more dynamic approach:
locals {
  non_prod_gateway  = { for k, v in aws_subnet.public_subnet : k => v.availability_zone if k != data.aws_availability_zones.all.names[0] && k != data.aws_availability_zones.all.names[1] }
  prod_nat_gateways = { for k, v in aws_subnet.public_subnet : k => v.availability_zone if k != data.aws_availability_zones.all.names[0] }
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "all" {
  filter {
    name   = "opt-in-status"
    values = ["opt-in-not-required"]
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "elastic_ip" {
  for_each = var.environment != "prod" ? local.non_prod_gateway : local.prod_nat_gateways

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "eip-${var.name_suffix}-${each.key}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed Elastic IP"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
  })
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw" {
  for_each      = aws_eip.elastic_ip
  allocation_id = each.value.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public_subnet[each.key].id

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "nat-gw-${var.name_suffix}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed NAT Gateway"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
  })
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {
  for_each = var.public_subnet

  availability_zone = each.key
  cidr_block        = each.value
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "public-subnet-${var.name_suffix}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed Subnet"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
    AZ          = each.key
  })
}

where the public_subnet would have to change to have a value:
public_subnet = {
  "eu-west-1a" = "10.10.0.0/24"
  "eu-west-1b" = "10.10.1.0/24"
  "eu-west-1c" = "10.10.2.0/24"
}

NOTE: the NAT Gateway should probably be in the public subnet(s), not private ones.

so, this one will create the nat in subnet_c for non prod and subnets a and b for prod right?

Yeah, I tried at least getting a random AZ but for some reason couldn't make it work.

I too tried with random_shuffle, but no luck. I think I am going to change the approach.

After outputting all objects, and using terraform console to try objects outputs, I came up with this, which works. It is a little cumbersome though, which is what I wanted to avoid.
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw" {
  count         = length(aws_eip.elastic_ip)
  allocation_id = aws_eip.elastic_ip[count.index].allocation_id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public_subnet[keys(aws_subnet.public_subnet)[count.index]].id

  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "nat-gw-${var.name_suffix}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed NAT Gateway"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
  })
}

To deconstruct the following statement:
aws_subnet.public_subnet[keys(aws_subnet.public_subnet)[count.index]].id

I am using the variable in the example because it is terraform console, and I didn't have access to the actual object.
> var.public_subnet
tomap({
  "subnet_a" = {
    "az" = "eu-west-1a"
    "cidr" = "10.10.0.0/24"
    "id" = "id-123"
  }
  "subnet_b" = {
    "az" = "eu-west-1b"
    "cidr" = "10.10.1.0/24"
    "id" = "id-456"
  }
  "subnet_c" = {
    "az" = "eu-west-1c"
    "cidr" = "10.10.2.0/24"
    "id" = "id-789"
  }
})
> keys(var.public_subnet)
tolist([
  "subnet_a",
  "subnet_b",
  "subnet_c",
])
> keys(var.public_subnet)[0]
"subnet_a"
> var.public_subnet[keys(var.public_subnet)[0]].id
"id-123"

I guess here what really helps me is that keys() returns a list, so I can iterate with count.

I would personally approach this by challenging the first assumption that it's necessary to use count because the NAT gateways and EIPs don't correlate one-to-one with the subnets. It's certainly true that it's considerably easier when there's a one-to-one correspondence, but it is also possible to write a more complicated expression that describes a one-to-many correspondence.
For example:
locals {
  nat_gateway_count = var.environment == "stg" ? 1 : 2

  nat_gateways = tomap(merge([
    for subnet_key, subnet in aws_subnet.public_subnet : {
      for idx in range(local.nat_gateway_count) :
      "${subnet_key}-${var.name_suffix}-${idx}" => {
        subnet_id = subnet.id
      }
    }
  ]...))
}

The merge function call means that local.nat_gateways will be flattened into a single map of objects with one element for each NAT gateway, but when the environment isn't "stg" that set will have two elements per subnet instead of just one.
You can then use this map as the for_each for both your NAT gateways and their Elastic IPs, since it seems like there's a one-to-one relationship between those:
resource "aws_eip" "elastic_ip" {
  for_each = local.nat_gateways

  vpc = true
  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "eip-${each.key}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed Elastic IP"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
  })
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw" {
  for_each = local.nat_gateways

  allocation_id = aws_eip.elastic_ip[each.key].id
  subnet_id     = each.value.subnet_id
  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    Name        = "nat-gw-${each.key}"
    Description = "Terraform Managed NAT Gateway"
    Project     = var.project
    Environment = var.environment
  })
}

For the value of var.public_subnet you included in your question, and assuming for the sake of example that var.name_suffix just matches var.environment, this should declare the following instances when environment is "stg":

aws_eip.elastic_ip["eip-subnet_a-stg-0"]
aws_nat_gateway.nat_gw["nat-gw-subnet_a-stg-0"]
aws_eip.elastic_ip["eip-subnet_b-stg-0"]
aws_nat_gateway.nat_gw["nat-gw-subnet_b-stg-0"]
aws_eip.elastic_ip["eip-subnet_c-stg-0"]
aws_nat_gateway.nat_gw["nat-gw-subnet_c-stg-0"]

...but the following if environment were "prd"

aws_eip.elastic_ip["eip-subnet_a-prd-0"]
aws_nat_gateway.nat_gw["nat-gw-subnet_a-prd-0"]
aws_eip.elastic_ip["eip-subnet_a-prd-1"]
aws_nat_gateway.nat_gw["nat-gw-subnet_a-prd-1"]
aws_eip.elastic_ip["eip-subnet_b-prd-0"]
aws_nat_gateway.nat_gw["nat-gw-subnet_b-prd-0"]
aws_eip.elastic_ip["eip-subnet_b-prd-1"]
aws_nat_gateway.nat_gw["nat-gw-subnet_b-prd-1"]
aws_eip.elastic_ip["eip-subnet_c-prd-0"]
aws_nat_gateway.nat_gw["nat-gw-subnet_c-prd-0"]
aws_eip.elastic_ip["eip-subnet_c-prd-1"]
aws_nat_gateway.nat_gw["nat-gw-subnet_c-prd-1"]


your example creates 1 Elastic IP and 1 NAT GW in each AZ when it's staging, and 2 of each in each AZ when it's prod. But what I need is 1 in total when it's staging and 2 in total when it's prod.

Ahh yes, I did misunderstand. Your mention of using for_each with the subnets and the need to relate the NAT gateways to subnets made me think you wanted a separate gateway for each subnet. One way you could adapt my approach to that requirement is to have an extra step of first selecting either one or two of your keys from var.public_subnet, such as by toset(slice(sort(keys(var.public_subnet)), 0, local.nat_gateway_count)), and then add an if clause to the for expression in local.nat_gateways to filter elements where subnet_key is not in that reduced set of keys.
